# Can not get radius value from Editable Circle onRadiusChanged event

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, react-google-maps

I am new to React Google Maps. I'm unable to get radius value from Circle.

https://github.com/JustFly1984/react-google-maps-api

I want to get circle redius `onRadiusChanged` event.

**index.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import Map from './Map';
import './style.css';

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Map
        googleMapURL="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDurZQBXjtSzKeieXwtFeGe-jhZu-HEGQU&libraries=drawing"
        loadingElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        containerElement={<div style={{ height: `400px` }} />}
        mapElement={<div style={{ height: `100%` }} />}
        center={{ lat: -33.8665433, lng: 151.1956316 }}
        zoom={15}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

**map.js**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import {
  withScriptjs,
  withGoogleMap,
  GoogleMap,
  Marker,
  Circle
} from "react-google-maps";

class MyMapComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          radius: 50
        }
  }

  updateRadius(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <GoogleMap
        defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        defaultCenter={this.props.center}
      >
      <Marker google={this.props.google}
        name={'Dolores park'}
        draggable={true}
        onDragEnd={this.onMarkerDragEnd}
        position={this.props.center}
      />
        <Circle
          center={this.props.center}
          options={{
            strokeColor: "#FF0000",
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 1,
            fillColor: "#FF0000",
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            clickable: false,
            draggable: false,
            editable: true,
            visible: true,
            radius: this.state.radius, //Calculation in Meter
            zIndex: 1
          }}
          onRadiusChanged={this.updateRadius}
        />
      </GoogleMap>
    );
  }
}

export default withScriptjs(withGoogleMap(MyMapComponent));
```

Result -

> undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onRadiusChanged` (as the underlying  [`center_changed` event](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Circle.center_changed) for a `Circle` class ) event does not accept any arguments. Since `onRadiusChanged` event handler method is not bound with its component instance in your example, the *updated radius* could be determined like this:

```
updateRadius() {
    const updatedRadius = this.getRadius();
}
```

where `this` refers to native [`Circle` object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/polygon#Circle).